# Need recommendations of team collaboration systems

Tags: php, open-source, tfsbuild

A small team needs a system where they can post to a wall and the other team members can comment.

They would have a dashboard that allows them to see all recent activity within a glance.

They also need to post files to their posts.

I tried out OpenAtrium.com and I feel it is great, but it is overkill for the scope of this project.

I thought of writing a dead simple system myself, but thought I'd try this avenue before.

I would prefer it be in php, mysql, open-source.

Comment: I don't see why you shouldn't code your own system, should be pretty simple too.

Comment: If it was internal I for sure use node.js. You could even make it realtime without almost no effort thanks to the really good socket.io library. I think you could write something really cool within a day(if you were able to program javascript) and be able to extend it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few of the teams I've been a part of have opted to use parts of the 37signals suite, namely Basecamp for tracking to-do items and files, and Campfire for team chatting.

It's not open source as you requested, but they do the job and they do it well.